# Dynamically allocating a 2D array of object pointers in a class

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, pointers

I'm struggling at the moment with the idea of dynamically allocating arrays at runtime. Coming from Java, used to just declaring the arrays in the class skeleton and only needing the size in the implementation.

This is what I've found to dynamically allocate 2D arrays:

```
Grid.h   
Block** grid;

Grid.cpp
grid = new Block*[size]
for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
    grid[i] = new Block[size]
```

This works pretty okay, although dealing with objects I've always been told that using pointers to objects rather than storing the objects themselves is much better performance wise. So when I tried to make the second dimension of arrays pointers like this:

```
Grid.cpp
grid = new Block*[size]
    for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
        grid[i] = new Block*[size];
```

When I changed my code to this, I got an error:

```
error: assigning to 'Block *' from incompatible type 'Block **'; dereference with *
        grid[i] = new Block* [size];
                ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                  *
```

Being slightly new to the C++ ways of doing things, can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Or even if I'm trying to do the wrong thing entirely?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `new T` has type `T *`. Hence, `new Block *` has type `Block **`. `grid` has type `Block **` so `grid[i]` has type `Block *`. The two aren't the same. By the way, why not `std::vector<std::vector<Block>>`?

Comment: Oh, so when creating objects with the `new` keyword, a pointer to the object is returned by default?

I've been told that these dynamically allocated arrays are faster and more efficient than creating 2D vectors of objects. Also, will I need to do manual cleanup in the deconstructor?

Comment: "a pointer to the object is returned by default?" – how **else** could you **possibly** do dynamic allocation? "I've been told that these dynamically allocated arrays are faster and more efficient than creating 2D vectors of objects" – um, nope. Not as a general truth, at the least (whoever told you that BS was… utterly, hopelessly wrong.)

Comment: I'm still learning here, so I wasn't quite sure.

Alright, well good to know for the future! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Whenever you think "dynamic array" when programming in C++, your next thought should be about [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Not using pointers will simplify very much.

Comment: As for your error, look at the code presented by the compiler in the error message, and then look at the code you present here to us. Do that look the same to you? The code you show us is correct, the actual code you have is not. My guess is that the error you have in your actual code is because of copy-pasting, while the correct code in the question is because you rewrote it.

Comment: The first code for Grid.cpp is the implementation that I found, but I didn't know that `new Block[size]` is an array of Block pointers. The second implementation, just above the error is my code trying to make the second array pointers.

Comment: In the code you show you say `grid[i] = new Block[size]`. This is correct. In the code you actually have and the compiler complains about you have `grid[i] = new Block*[size]` which is not correct. And now in your comment you say that `new Block[size]` is an array of block *pointers*, it is not. The expression `new Block[size]` gives you a pointer to an array of `Block` instances, while `new Block*[size]` (note the asterisk) gives you a pointer to an array of pointers to `Block` instances.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, in the question I stated that I was looking to create the arrays as pointers to Block objects. The first implementation works, but they are not pointers to Block objects, this is why I tried the second implementation which gave me the error.

Comment: You are using C-style arrays and pointers. That's what you are doing wrong. Don't believe everything you've been told, go learn std::vector and use it.

Comment: Then you must become a [three star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer). Or like I suggested before, use `std::vector` (as in `std::vector<std::vector<Block*>>`).

Comment: Also, *why* do you need to have a matrix of *pointers*? In modern C++ there is seldom a need to use pointers outside of polymorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dynamic 2D array is an array of pointers to arrays. 
You should initialize first the array of pointer, then the others array using a loop.

Here an example using int that creates an array[rowCount][colCount]:

```
int** array = new int*[rowCount];
for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; ++i)
    array[i] = new int[colCount];
```

otherwise of course you can always have a 2D array on the stack by using:

```
int array[rowCount][colCount];
```

Comment: Thank you, I did get that far with the implementation. I was asking how to create the arrays as pointers to the type rather than just a standard array of `int` for example. I've recently been told that the `new` keyword creates and returns a pointer though.

Comment: `int array[rowCount][colCount];` VLA's aren't standard c++.

Comment: so you actually might want to use std::vector or std::array

Comment: This is seeming like the best option, I think. Thank you @Stefano.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ i had not specified but of course row & col Count had to be constant! thanks for the remark!

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend you writing this type of code, but if you still want to hack your way out you can do something like this:-

```
int main()
{
Block*** grid;      

grid = new Block**[10];         
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
{       
    grid[i] = new Block*[10];   
}

/*Here, we have created a grid of pointers*/

/*

|Block**[10]|

|Block[0] **|------------->|Block* [10]|
|Block[1] **|------------->|Block* [10]|
|Block[2] **|------------->|Block* [10]|
|Block[3] **|------------->|Block* [10]|
..
..
|Block[9] **|------------->|Block* [10]|

*/

for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
{       
    for(int j = 0 ; j < 10 ; j++)
    {
        grid[i][j] = new Block[10]; 
    }
}

/*

|Block**[10]|

|Block[0] **|------------->|Block* [0]|------------->|Block1|Block2| .. |Block10|
                           |Block* [1]|------------->|Block1|Block2| .. |Block10|
                           |Block* [2]|------------->|Block1|Block2| .. |Block10|
                           ..
                           |Block* [9]|------------->|Block1|Block2| .. |Block10|


|Block[1] **|------------->|Block* [0]|------------->|Block1|Block2| .. |Block10|
                           |Block* [1]|------------->|Block1|Block2| .. |Block10|
                           |Block* [2]|------------->|Block1|Block2| .. |Block10|
                           ..
                           |Block* [9]|------------->|Block1|Block2| .. |Block10|          
|Block[2] **|
|Block[3] **|
..
..
|Block[9] **|

*/
 }
```

Comment: @tobi303 What i meant is that wherever possible he should use `smart pointers` or `std::vector` that will manage the memory, rather than using bare pointers

Comment: you should mention this in your answer

Answer (score 0):

Use a linear representation of 2d array:

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> array(new int[rowCount*colCount]);

for (size_t r = 0; r < rowCount; r++)
  for (size_t c = 0; c < colCount; c++)
    (array.get())[r*colCount + c] = r*c;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alocating array of pointers can also be done in thread safe manner:

```
size_t allocatedRows = rowCount;
        try{
            array = new char*[allocatedRows];
            while(allocatedRows){
                --allocatedRows;
                array[allocatedRows] = new char[colCount];
            }
        }catch(std::bad_alloc& ex){
            while(++allocatedRows < lines)
                delete array[allocatedRows];
            delete array;
            throw;
        }
```

Two thing to note in code above:
1) allocatedRows is not decremented in [] operator, as behaviour would be undefined
2) After allocating array of pointers, dereferencing array elemnts has undefined behaviour(just like normal pointer without assignment). 
Please also keep in mind that in case above I didn't recovered from bad_alloc I just rethrowed, It can be logged somewhere else before call to termination. If You would like to create array of pointers from other user defined objects You could use std::uninitialized_copy or std::uninitialized_fill. 
Another way would be just to use vectors.